# Syncing iphones with Android phone

Tags: iphone, calendar, android

We run a small business, and the managers would like to have the calendars on their phones synced with each other so that they know what is going on with the other.  Most of them are using iphone and one is using an android phone.  Is there a calendar app that we can use.  Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

Your first option is to use a "third-party" app that works for both iPhone and Android. For example:

- http://synkmonkey.me/
- http://www.cozi.com/mobile-access.htm (I personally know someone that, IIRC, uses this)

---

Your other option is to use a shared calendar in a service such as Gmail. I personally think this solution is better. You have two options: either setup an arbitrary email account that all the managers use to sync their calendar to, such as [your-company-calendar]@gmail.com, or, you create a calendar, and if all the managers have their own Gmail accounts, make them all owners of it. This allows you to use the default, built in, calendar app on both Android and iOS devices.

To set this up (I am generalizing the steps that work with both setups):

1. Log in to Google and create a calendar.
2. If everyone has their own Gmail accounts, share it with all the managers and make everyone an owner. If not, there is no need to share the calendar.
3. On iPhone (I'm assuming Android would be somewhat similar) create a new email account and log on to the new centralized Gmail account - if this is the route you want to take. After logging in to the account on each device, leave calendars on, but disable email.
4. If you aren't doing a centralized Gmail account, make sure everyone is signed into the Gmail accounts, on their phones, that you have used to make them owners of the calendars.

This should allow them to look up, and create events from the default calendar app on the devices.

Answer (score 1):

Shared Calenders work between Android and Iphone using Gmail on both phones. See these instructions [Shared Calendar](http://httgo.co/2013/05/11/shared-calendar-with-iphone-and-android/):

> 1. Create a Gmail account for the shared calendar. I recommend you create a new one instead of using a regular personal account.
> 2. On an iPhone open the Settings App and choose Mail, Contacts, Calendar, then “Add Account…”;  Choose Gmail as the account type enter the account information for your family calender account. Once finished go back to  the Mail, Contacts and Calendar  settings screen and scroll toward the bottom. Find the the “Default Calendar” setting and choose the new Gmail account you just added for your shared family calendar.
> 3. On an Android phone press the Gmail icon and choose “Add Account” (You can also add an account from the System Settings menu). Make sure you choose to sync the calendar during setup. After setting up the account ensure that the calendar for the new account is set to be display by checking under settings in the Calendar App. Unfortunately, I was not able to find a default calendar setting for new events on Android. You will need to make sure when create a new event that the right calendar is selected before saving the event.

Comment: Would you mind summarizing what is included in the link? Links can break as a result of the destination files being (re)moved.